# Glob and include current directory and recursive subdirectories

Tags: bash

Assume that I have the following directory structure:

```
file.txt
file.css
file.js
directory/file.txt
directory/file.css
directory/file.js
directory/subdirectory/file.txt
directory/subdirectory/file.css
directory/subdirectory/file.js
```

I want to be able to find all of the `txt` and `css` files in all directories (ideally without using `find` because I want the command that I write to be extensible). The list of file extensions should be in a variable named `FILE_PATTERN`.

The command should ultimately output:

- `directory/subdirectory/file.css`
- `directory/subdirectory/file.txt`
- `directory/file.css`
- `directory/file.txt`
- `file.css`
- `file.txt`

But each globbing pattern I am trying isn't returning the result:

```
$ FILE_PATTERN="{**/,}*.{css,txt}"
$ echo $FILE_PATTERN
# FAILS: Returns 0 results

$ FILE_PATTERN={**/,}*.{css,txt}
$ echo $FILE_PATTERN
# FAILS: Returns 0 results

$ echo {**/,}*.{css,txt}
# FAILS: Only returns:
directory/file.css directory/file.txt file.css file.txt
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you planning to provide feedback on the answer? Can you mark it accepted if it solved your problem?

Comment: The reason why your first two results were not successful is that bash only expands globs for arguments and not when assigning variables. That means now the variable contains the literal string (as if you had put quotes around them in your echo) and that will not be expanded afterwards.
The last one requires `shopt -s globstar`, which is not available in bash < 4.0 (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/379192/438671)

Comment: Sidenote: personally I would find it easier to read `{**,.}/whatever.txt` than `{**/,}whatever.txt` - but that is just a question of style :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you have against find, it can be made very extensible with a little effort (even on a MAC):

```
FILE_PATTERN=(txt css)

IFS='|'
find -E -iregex ".*(${FILE_PATTERN[*]})"
```

I do not have a mac to play with, but I think the -E option should work for you, if not, have a look at the man page :)

Comment: Hi Grail. Original reluctance to find was because of the syntax for -o, but this looks like the approach I need. Thanks!

Comment: Needed to add the dot: `find -E . -iregex ".*(${FILE_PATTERN[*]})"`

Answer (score 0):

Based on @grail's response, I ended up going for this:

```
FILE_EXTENSIONS="txt|css"
find -E . -iregex ".*\\/[^\\/]+\\.(${FILE_EXTENSIONS})\$"
./directory/file.css
./directory/file.txt
./directory/subdirectory/file.css
./directory/subdirectory/file.txt
./file.css
./file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your first two results were not successful is that bash only expands globs for arguments and not when assigning variables. That means now FILE_PATTERN contains the literal string (as if you had put quotes around them in your echo) and that will not be expanded afterwards.

The last one works without calling an external program, but requires `shopt -s globstar`, which is not available in bash < 4.0 (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/379192/438671) so and that is e.g. not working with the default bash of MacOS